# Unit vector perpendicular to two vectors

Tags: vector-analysis

Find a unit vector perpendicular to both the vectors:
$$\vec{A} = 2\hat{i}+3\hat{j}+\hat{k}$$
$$\vec{B} = \hat{i}-2\hat{j}+\hat{k}$$
I have tried to solve the question by finding unit vector along $\vec{A} \times \vec{B}$ but getting the wrong answer. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Remember that if $\overrightarrow{u}$ is any non-zero vector, then $\overrightarrow{u}/\|\overrightarrow{u}\|$ is a unit vector colinear to $\overrightarrow{u}$.

Comment: Your method seems reasonable.  What are you getting for your answer?

Comment: I am getting this answer: 1/root(75)*(5i+j-7k).

Comment: I think you have a sign error in a component of the answer.

Comment: Please elaborate how.

Comment: Your $j$ term should be $-j$.

Comment: Yes, your are correct. But still the correct answer is 1/root(83)*(7i-3j-5k)

Comment: The answer you are saying is "correct" is not perpendicular to the second given vector.

Comment: Okay I got it. Then the options given are incorrect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Only remember how you define $u\times v$
Like a determinant.
$u\times v=|\begin{pmatrix} 
u_1 & u_2 & u_3\\
v_1& v_2 & v_3 \\
i & j & k \\
\end{pmatrix}| $